# Twitter Bootstrap set badge to no fill (or outline)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, less, badge, outline

Anyone know how to change a twitter bootstrap badge (or label) from solid to outlined?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Add this CSS class to your badge :

```
.badge-outline {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Create overriden classes for other colors :

```
.badge-outline.badge-success {
    border-color: #468847;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 5 has support for the effect you want right out of the package. The [border classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/borders/) not only create an outline but allow for control of the color and thickness too.

This example uses `border` and `border-primary` on a badge to create the blue outline. To get the "3" to match the color of the outline, it also uses `text-primary`. Note that it uses just the `badge` class, not `badge-primary` because that would also change the background color to blue.

```html
<span class="badge border border-primary text-primary">3</span>
```

Comment: I tried manipulating border width of the outline using border-5 for example, which should affect the border thickness. But it does not work with badge outlines, it seems.

Answer (score 6):

Quick bootstrap 4 sass version

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .badge-outline-#{$color} {
    border: $border-width solid $value;
    color: $value !important;
    background: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The typical boostrap configuration for badges has these key parts related to your question (spread out in their `labels-badges.less`):

**Current Bootstrap**

```
.badge {
    color: @white;
    background-color: @grayLight;
    /* no border is set, just a border-radius: 9x */
}

.badge {
  // Important (red)
  &-important { background-color: @errorText; }
  &-important[href] { background-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); }

  // Warnings (orange)
  &-warning { background-color: @orange; }
  &-warning[href] { background-color: darken(@orange, 10%); }

  // Success (green)
  &-success { background-color: @successText; }
  &-success[href] { background-color: darken(@successText, 10%); }

  // Info (turquoise)
  &-info { background-color: @infoText; }
  &-info[href] { background-color: darken(@infoText, 10%); }

  // Inverse (black)
  &-inverse { background-color: @grayDark; }
  &-inverse[href] { background-color: darken(@grayDark, 10%); }
}
```

So you can override it by following that with something like this:

**Override in your later LESS code**

```
.badge {
    color: @black;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid @grayLight; /* set your border */
}

.badge {
  // Important (red)
  &-important { background-color: transparent;
                border-color: @errorText;
                color: #errorText; /* maybe change color? up to you. */
              }
  &-important[href] { background-color: transparent;
                      border-color: darken(@errorText, 10%); 
                      color: darken(@errorText, 10%); /* ??? */
              }

  etc... for -warning, -success, -info, -inverse
}
```